# Inject record into journey when record is created via the UI (No Code)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, event, contactbuilder

I am new to the Marketing Cloud (Marketo Background) and I need a little Journey Builder help.

We are currently hosting all of our records in a homegrown CRM and importing records as they are created via API. I want to have these records injected into a journey, I currently could create a custom API event but that is not ideal. Especially if we are going to hire on some JR marketers that don't write code.

Is there a way to build this within the UI without writing code?

1. My thought was that I would just use the "API Event" entry source, pick the data extension the record is stored in, and add the criteria "Lead_id IS NOT null". Unfortunately, that didn't work for me.
2. The Contact Data entry source did work for me but I don't want to rely on something that will be retired soon.
3. Also, the Data Extension Entry source does not work because we need entrance into the Journey as the lead is created, not an hour.

Any insight on this would be so helpful... I have been banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out within the UI. It must be possible.